# If the king is in check, and the piece that is holding it in check is directly adjacent from the king can the king take it?

Tags: strategy

If the king is in check, and the piece that is holding it in check is directly adjacent from the king, can the king take it?

Comment: If the piece is not protected, then the king can take it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as capturing the checking piece would not *also* cause the King to be in check, yes!

---

In the position below, the White Queen is giving check. After `...Kxf7`, the Black King is *no longer* in check, so it is indeed a legal move.

```
[FEN "rnbqkb1r/pppp1Qpp/5n2/4p3/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1KBNR b KQkq - 0 0"]

1...Kxf7
```

---

However, it is illegal to make any move that places your own King in check. If you did, the opponent would be able to capture your King immediately. Since you can never actually *capture* a King in a game of Chess, making a move that would allow it is illegal.

So, if White's Queen is "protected" by another piece (such as a Bishop, below), the Black's King *cannot* capture it, as doing so would leave his King still in check. In fact, in the position below (the "scholar's mate"), Black is **checkmated** because he has no moves that would not result in his still being in check.

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/pppp1Qpp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1K1NR b KQkq - 0 0"]

1...Kxf7 2.Bxf7
```

Remember that in the position above, `1...Kxf7 2.Bxf7` are given as *examples*: neither move is actually legal, as Black is *already checkmated in the starting position!*